# 2D Array reference in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to do a subprogram in Perl that will load data into 2D array:

```
sub load {
    my $separator = shift;
    my $i = 0;

    while(<STDIN>) {
        @temp = split(/$separator/, $_);
        @arr[$i] = \@temp;
        $i++;
    }
    return @arr;
}

@array = load(":");
print "$array[0][0] $array[1][0]";
```

example file, we can name it x:

```
a:b:c:d
z:x:c:v
```

executing script:

```
cat x | perl name
```

and the answer should be "a z" instead of "z z". I know that it must be something wrong with \@temp, but I do not have idea how to make it correct.
Does anyone could help me?

Regards

Comment: there is not any warnings

Comment: You keep reloading the same array `@temp` with different data.  If you'd used `use strict;` and `my @temp`, then you'd get the result you expected — as in the answer by @toolic.  Using both `use strict;` and `use warnings;` is good policy. Experts do it to prevent them making silly mistakes; beginners should do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of having a self-contained example, I replaced `STDIN` with `DATA`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub load {
    my $separator = shift;
    my @arr;

    while(<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my @temp = split(/$separator/, $_);
        push @arr, \@temp;
    }
    return @arr;
}

my @array = load(":");
print "$array[0][0] $array[1][0]\n";

__DATA__
a:b:c:d
z:x:c:v
```

Comment: Or just `push @arr, [ split /$separator/ ];`

Comment: To make my code runnable in a correct way, I should have add `my` here: `my @temp = split(/$separator/, $_);` Thanks for help :)